# How to freeze and invert animation in ViewPager?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

During a swipe from `View A` to `View B`, when the user releases in the ViewPager 
- I would like the ViewPager to freeze at the current point and to animate back, to `View A`.

How should I implement that?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done that before, but my guess would be to create your own CustomViewPager and make it do the new features for you.

[This is the link](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java#ViewPager.determineTargetPage%28int,float,int,int%29) to the method of the ViewPager that handles which page is to be displayed next.

I would try to add some kind of delay here for your freeze-effect and tweak the float-values which trigger whether you successfully swipe or pop back.